# SearchAllSubDirectories Inefficient Under Load

Tags: vb.net, performance, visual-studio, file-io

To detail the problem a bit here, I need to obtain the file "DKIM.txt" hundreds, potentially thousands of times from within different directories.

The file will always appear in a folders such as:

C:\CONX\Users\Jason\222\DKIM.txt

C:\CONX\Users\Donald\12\DKIM.txt

C:\CONX\Users\Yuri\1251\DKIM.txt

The folder depth will **never** change, the username and the identifier (eg. Jason, and 222) will **always** change.

My currently working code is as follows:

```
For Each UserDirectory As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\CONX\Users", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "DKIM.txt")
     Console.WriteLine(UserDirectory)
Next
```

The problem with the above is it's slow on our extremely populated machines. Their load at times can be 80-90% CPU and simply cycling through all the sub directories to search for one file we know will always exist is inefficient and slow.

So my question is, how would I just wildcard the directory username and identifier.

Example: Return all directories that match: C:\CONX\Users\*\*\DKIM.txt where * is our wildcard.

Thank you.

Comment: A disk drive is not a substitute for a database engine by a long shot.  Console.WriteLine is not a substitute for a log file by a long shot.  It is slow because you made bad design choices.  "Throw everything away and do it right" is not an answer we can ever post, even though it is the only correct one.

Comment: I think you may be jumping to conclusions. The CONX software stores huge files and directories. (some directories are upward of 50GB) And the Console.WriteLine is for debugging purposes in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Search with a predefined depth limit while also matching with a filename. This will eliminate wasted CPU cycles recursively searching for the file we knew existed in each directory.

```
Public Sub GetFiles(ByVal strFileFilter As String, ByVal strDirectory As String, ByVal intDepthLimit As Integer, ByVal intCurrentDepth As Integer)
 Dim folderInfo As New DirectoryInfo(strDirectory)

 ' Is the current depth on this recursion less than our limit?
 ' If so, find any directories and get into them by calling GetFiles recursively (incrementing depth count)
 If intCurrentDepth < intDepthLimit Then
      Dim directories() As DirectoryInfo
      directories = folderInfo.GetDirectories()

      For Each fDirectory In directories
           ' Recursively call ourselves incrementing the depth using the given folder path.
           GetFiles(strFileFilter, fDirectory.FullName, intDepthLimit, intCurrentDepth + 1)
      Next
 End If

 ' After we can't go further down, add any files which match our filter to listbox (in this case lstFiles)
 Dim files() As FileInfo
 files = folderInfo.GetFiles(strFileFilter)

 For Each fFile In files
      lstFiles.Items.Add(fFile.FullName)
 Next
End Sub
```

Source: http://www.coderslexicon.com/playing-with-recursive-directory-diving-in-vb-net/

eg. GetFiles("DKIM.txt", "C:\CONX\Users", 3, 0)

Dropped the execution time for hundreds of large directories from multiple seconds using FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories to less than half a second.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of sub directory, it could be faster to do your own custom search. You could do that search yourself with [GetDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx).

Loop All directory under C:\CONX\Users
Loop All sub-directory
Check if that sub-directory contains the file.

This also depends if each username have multiple directory under them. I would also suggest to cache the result. If you only need to run it once, it might not matter that it's slow.

Also, Console.WriteLine is very slow. You could write in a file instead you might see some improvement.

Comment: Your response got me closest to the answer, which I'll be posting in a moment. +1

Answer (score 0):

As Hans Passant pointed out the flaws so eloquently I'm going to go ahead and propose what I think can work. Here it goes.

Use a program to monitor your \Users folder for any file changes (created/deleted) and add a trigger to run a batch script to update a text file where you maintain all your users and identifier. You can write your own window process (daemon) if you like for this or use an off the shelf software like Watch 4 Folder. Here is a guide for that describes it's usability http://www.guidingtech.com/9861/automate-folder-actions-windows-watch-4-folder/

Now you will just be searching the new text file (master list) as opposed to traversing the entire directory and sub directory structure. It will be better if you can store the master list of user/identifier in the database and use a batch script or powershell to update the database.

Good luck.

Comment: I responded to Hans, his assumptions are incorrect. As for your suggestion, while appreciated it's not entirely viable to deploy the Watch 4 application over this network just to monitor one specific file in each folder. .net is entirely capable of handling this assuming the right method is used to target the file.